# No hace caso a DO WHILE, hace un cálculo y terminal la ejecución. ¿Qué sucede?

Tags: c++, c

No hace caso al do while. A pesar de tener un scanf tras "Seguir calculando otro s o n:", no pide al usuario introducir un caracter. Directamente termina la ejecución.
¿Qué está mal? Gracias.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
    float num1, num2, result;
    char seguir, opcion;

    printf("¡Bienvenido a la calculadora!");
    
    do {
        printf("\nElige suma resta multiplicacion division:");  
        scanf("%c",&opcion);
        
        switch(opcion){
            case '+':
                printf("Num1:");
                scanf("%f",&num1);
                printf("Num2:");
                scanf("%f",&num2);
                result = num1 + num2;
            break;
            
            case '-':
                printf("Num1:");
                scanf("%f",&num1);
                printf("Num2:");
                scanf("%f",&num2);
                result = num1 - num2;
            break;
            
            default: puts ("error");    
        }
        
        printf("Resultado: %f",result);
        printf("\nSeguir calculando otro s o n:");
        scanf("%c",&seguir);
        
    }while(seguir != 's');
    printf("%c",seguir);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema esta en el scanf, debes añadir un espacio en blanco antes de %c para omitir los espacios en blanco y saltos de linea quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
 scanf(" %c",&seguir);
```

y el otro detalle es que en el While debe quedar así.

```
 }while(seguir != 'n');
```

Para que en el caso de que no quieras continuar respondas n(No) y de esta manera salir del ciclo, es solo un pequeño detalle.

Answer (score 0):

En C++, los ciclos se repiten siempre que la condición sea verdadera.

Por lo tanto, si ingresas **s** porque quieres seguir, la condición `seguir != 's'` se evalúa como falso.

Cambia el `!=` por `==`. Eso debería arreglar el problema.